# Tracking user on single page website with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Recently I've faced a problem to track user on a "single page website" with Google Analytics. I want to share my solution. Please see the answer below.

Comment: You might separate this into a *question* and an *answer*.  I noticed that Google Analytics reclassified a bunch of visits to a single page calculator site from bounces into regular visits when I started sending track events for button pushing events, so anything that feeds Google a little more info and lets you track it is possibly useful in less obvious ways as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I've faced a problem to track user on a "single page website" with Google Analytics. I want to share my solution.

----- Page layout -----

```
1a. Header with logo and menu (links scroll page down to selected chapter)
2a. Section with big paralax bakground
2b. Chapter header <section><h2>Title 1</h2></section>
2c. Chapter's content <div>content</div>
3a. Section with big paralax bakground
3b. Chapter header <section><h2>Title 2</h2></section>
3c. Chapter's content <div>content</div>
...
Na. Section with big paralax bakground
Nb. Chapter header <section><h2>Title N</h2></section>
Nc. Chapter's content <div>content</div>
```

----- Requirements -----

1. Algorithm must detect when the page is scrolled down so the selected chapter is visible for user.
2. Algorithm must detect that user actually spend some time to familiarize himself with the content of the chapter. This fact must be reported to Google Analytics.
3. Algorithm cannot report that user read the chapter, when he just scroll through it.

---- Algorithm -----

1. Wait for page to load
2. Create a list of chapters and it's position in relation to the top border of the website.
3. When desired chapter is visible for user, than this condition must be rechecked after certain period of time to prove that user actually spend some time reading the content.
4. If above conditions are fulfilled than report this fact to Google Analytics.

---- Example Code -----

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var scrollstat = []

// Preparing array of chapters and positions
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("section").each(function() {
        var ts = {};
        ts["offset"] = $(this).offset();
        str = $("h2", this).html();
        ts["name"] = "SECTION-"+str.replace(" ","-")+"/";
        ts["checked"] = false;
        ts["timer"] = false;
        scrollstat.push(ts);
     });
});

//Checking that user is still on the same chapter
function doublecheck(ii) {
    scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    max = scrollpos + 300;
    min = scrollpos;
    if (scrollstat[ii].checked == false && scrollstat[ii].offset.top > min
    && scrollstat[ii].offset.top < max) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', (location.pathname + location.search
        + scrollstat[ii].name)]);
        scrollstat[ii].checked = true;
    }
    console.log(scrollstat[ii].offset.top+','+min+','+max);
    scrollstat[ii].timer = false;
}


//Separate function for setting timer to count 3s
//If user don't scroll to other chapter within this time
//event is reported to GA

function settimer(ii) {
    scrollstat[ii].timer = true; 
    setTimeout(function() {doublecheck(ii);},3000);  
}

//Handling scrolling event
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scrollpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    max = scrollpos + 300;
    min = scrollpos;
    for (index = 0; index < scrollstat.length; ++index) {
        if (scrollstat[index].checked == false &&
        scrollstat[index].timer == false &&
        scrollstat[index].offset.top > min &&
        scrollstat[index].offset.top < max) {
              settimer(index);
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

MAX and MIN variables are estimated experimentally. In my case I assumed that chapter title must be scrolled to the top of the screen.

As a result of the above script, each chapters are reported to GA as separate page visits with address like: "/SECTION-chapter-title/"

Comment: Is this still the best approach to check which sections of a single page website were seen/scrolled to by a user?